# Can't ping through IPsec

Tags: encryption, vpn, cisco, ipsec, asa

I have configured IPsec using asdm site-to-site VPN wizard. Based on "show crypto isakmp sa" and "show ipsec sa" the tunnel seems to be up and fine. However pinging from one site to the other doesn't work.

---

show crypto isakmp sa:

'''

```
There are no IKEv1 SAs

IKEv2 SAs:

Session-id:54544, Status:UP-ACTIVE, IKE count:1, CHILD count:1

Tunnel-id Local Remote Status Role
57139155 200.200.200.1/500 200.200.200.5/500 READY INITIATOR
Encr: AES-CBC, keysize: 256, Hash: SHA96, DH Grp:5, Auth sign: PSK, Auth verify: PSK
Life/Active Time: 86400/139 sec
Child sa: local selector 192.168.100.0/0 - 192.168.100.255/65535
remote selector 192.168.200.0/0 - 192.168.200.255/65535
ESP spi in/out: 0xdb8b7bd7/0x28ced118
```

### '''

show ipsec sa:

'''

```
interface: outside
Crypto map tag: outside_map, seq num: 1, local addr: 200.200.200.1

access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0
local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.200.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
current_peer: 200.200.200.5


#pkts encaps: 3, #pkts encrypt: 3, #pkts digest: 3
#pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
#pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
#pkts not compressed: 3, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
#pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
#PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
#TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
#Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
#send errors: 0, #recv errors: 0

local crypto endpt.: 200.200.200.1/500, remote crypto endpt.: 200.200.200.5/500
path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 74(44), media mtu 1500
PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: copy-df
ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
current outbound spi: 28CED118
current inbound spi : DB8B7BD7

inbound esp sas:
spi: 0xDB8B7BD7 (3683351511)
SA State: active
transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac no compression
in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, PFS Group 2, IKEv2, }
slot: 0, conn_id: 223412224, crypto-map: outside_map
sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4239360/28770)
IV size: 16 bytes
replay detection support: Y
Anti replay bitmap:
0x00000000 0x00000001
outbound esp sas:

spi: 0x28CED118 (684642584)
SA State: active
transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac no compression
in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, PFS Group 2, IKEv2, }
slot: 0, conn_id: 223412224, crypto-map: outside_map
sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4285439/28770)
IV size: 16 bytes
replay detection support: Y
Anti replay bitmap:
0x00000000 0x00000001
```

### '''

Here are the ASAs configuration:

HQ:

'''

```
ASA Version 9.8(1)
!

hostname ciscoasa

enable password $sha512$5000$nXzpn8V4a0y6//kETGJOdA==$RlNWonyJ9Sqh5ImXBjyPBg== pbkdf2

xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4

xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6

xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4

xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6

xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain

names



!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/2

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/3

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!



interface GigabitEthernet0/4

nameif outside

security-level 0

ip address 200.200.200.1 255.255.255.252

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/5

nameif inside

security-level 100

ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/6

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface Management0/0

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

ftp mode passive

object network riffa

subnet 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0

object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24

subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0

object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24

subnet 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0

object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1

network-object 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0

network-object object riffa

access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 object-group 
DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1

pager lines 23

mtu outside 1500

mtu inside 1500

no failover

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

no asdm history enable



arp timeout 14400

no arp permit-nonconnected

arp rate-limit 8192

nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 destination 
static riffa riffa no-proxy-arp route-lookup

nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 destination 
static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.1

68.200.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup

nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 destination 
static DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 no-pro

xy-arp route-lookup

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.200.200.2 1

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

timeout floating-conn 0:00:00

timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15

timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10

user-identity default-domain LOCAL

aaa authentication login-history

http server enable

http 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 inside

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport



crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES

protocol esp encryption des

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES

protocol esp encryption 3des

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES

protocol esp encryption aes

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192


protocol esp encryption aes-192

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256

protocol esp encryption aes-256

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap

crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs

crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 200.200.200.5

crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-
192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA

ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5

crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES

crypto map outside_map interface outside



crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

no validation-usage

crl configure

crypto ca trustpool policy

auto-import

crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

quit

crypto ikev2 policy 1

encryption aes-256

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 10

encryption aes-192

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 20

encryption aes

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 30


encryption 3des

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 40

encryption des

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 enable outside

crypto ikev1 enable outside



rypto ikev1 policy 10

authentication pre-share

encryption aes-256

hash sha


group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 20

authentication rsa-sig

encryption aes-256

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 40

authentication pre-share

encryption aes-192

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 50

authentication rsa-sig

encryption aes-192

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 70

authentication pre-share

encryption aes

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 80

authentication rsa-sig

encryption aes

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 100

authentication pre-share

encryption 3des



hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 110

authentication rsa-sig

encryption 3des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 130

authentication pre-share

encryption des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 140

authentication rsa-sig

encryption des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

telnet timeout 5

ssh stricthostkeycheck

ssh timeout 5

ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1

console timeout 0

management-access inside

threat-detection basic-threat

threat-detection statistics access-list

no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept

group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.5 internal

group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.5 attributes

vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

tunnel-group 200.200.200.5 type ipsec-l2l

tunnel-group 200.200.200.5 general-attributes

default-group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.5

tunnel-group 200.200.200.5 ipsec-attributes

ikev1 pre-shared-key *****



ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****

ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****

!

class-map inspection_default

match default-inspection-traffic

!
!

policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512

no tcp-inspection

policy-map global_policy

class inspection_default

inspect ip-options

inspect netbios

inspect rtsp

inspect sunrpc

inspect tftp

inspect xdmcp

inspect dns preset_dns_map

inspect ftp

inspect h323 h225

inspect h323 ras

inspect rsh

inspect esmtp

inspect sqlnet

inspect sip

inspect skinny

policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_2

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512

no tcp-inspection

policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_1

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512

no tcp-inspection


!

service-policy global_policy global

prompt hostname context

call-home reporting anonymous prompt 2

call-home

profile License

destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService

destination transport-method http

profile CiscoTAC-1

no active

: end
```

'''

---

Branch

'''

```
ASA Version 9.8(1)

!

hostname ciscoasa

enable password $sha512$5000$EXcoX1JPozcQiQa/55KxWg==$+LFF0QFvQKUOU3KSuzUOHA== pbkdf2

xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4

xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6

xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4

xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6

xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain

xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain

names



!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/2

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/3

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!



interface GigabitEthernet0/4

nameif outside

security-level 0

ip address 200.200.200.5 255.255.255.252

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/5

nameif inside

security-level 100

ip address 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.0

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/6

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

interface Management0/0

shutdown

no nameif

no security-level

no ip address

!

ftp mode passive

object network hq

subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0

object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24

subnet 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0

object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24

subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0

access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0 object hq

pager lines 23

mtu outside 1500

mtu inside 1500

no failover

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

no asdm history enable

arp timeout 14400

no arp permit-nonconnected

arp rate-limit 8192

nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24 destination 
static hq hq no-proxy-arp route-lookup

nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.200.0_24 destination 
static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.1

68.100.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.200.200.6 1

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

timeout floating-conn 0:00:00

timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15

timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10

user-identity default-domain LOCAL

aaa authentication login-history

http server enable

http 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0 inside

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac



crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES

protocol esp encryption des

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES

protocol esp encryption 3des

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES

protocol esp encryption aes

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192

protocol esp encryption aes-192

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256

protocol esp encryption aes-256

protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap

crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs

crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 200.200.200.1

crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-
192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA

ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5

crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES

crypto map outside_map interface outside

crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

no validation-usage

crl configure

crypto ca trustpool policy

auto-import



pto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

quit

crypto ikev2 policy 1

encryption aes-256

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 10

encryption aes-192

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 20

encryption aes

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 30

encryption 3des

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 40

encryption des

integrity sha

group 5 2

prf sha

lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 enable outside

crypto ikev1 enable outside

crypto ikev1 policy 10

authentication pre-share

encryption aes-256

hash sha



group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 40

authentication pre-share

encryption aes-192

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 50

authentication rsa-sig

encryption aes-192

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 70

authentication pre-share

encryption aes

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 80

authentication rsa-sig

encryption aes

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 100

authentication pre-share

encryption 3des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 110

authentication rsa-sig

encryption 3des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 130



authentication pre-share

encryption des


hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

crypto ikev1 policy 140

authentication rsa-sig

encryption des

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

telnet timeout 5

ssh stricthostkeycheck

ssh timeout 5

ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1

console timeout 0

management-access inside

threat-detection basic-threat

threat-detection statistics access-list

no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept

group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.1 internal


group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.1 attributes

vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

tunnel-group 200.200.200.1 type ipsec-l2l

tunnel-group 200.200.200.1 general-attributes

default-group-policy GroupPolicy_200.200.200.1

tunnel-group 200.200.200.1 ipsec-attributes

ikev1 pre-shared-key *****

ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****

ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****

!

class-map inspection_default

match default-inspection-traffic

!

!

policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

parameters

message-length maximum client auto



message-length maximum 512

no tcp-inspection

policy-map global_policy


class inspection_default

inspect ip-options

inspect netbios

inspect rtsp

inspect sunrpc

inspect tftp

inspect xdmcp

inspect dns preset_dns_map

inspect ftp

inspect h323 h225

inspect h323 ras

inspect rsh

inspect esmtp

inspect sqlnet

inspect sip

inspect skinny

policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_2

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512


no tcp-inspection

policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_1

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512

no tcp-inspection

!

service-policy global_policy global

prompt hostname context

call-home reporting anonymous prompt 2

call-home

profile License

destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService

destination transport-method http

profile CiscoTAC-1

no active
```

### '''

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. After pinging from site A to site B, I found that site A encrypts the traffic and send it, on the other hand, site B receives the traffic, decrypt it, but does not encrypt and send reply. I was thinking that Site B ASA keeps on denying the traffic therefore it does not encrypt and reply, however that was not the case. Site B decrypts the traffic and forward it to the inside host (windows 7), but inside host's firewall denies icmp traffic, therefore there is no reply. So I have just shutdown inside host firewall and IPsec ran smoothly and ping succeed. It is funny that this issue been floating over the blogs and techs community for years and many could no find answers, it turned to be a simple issue.